Google admob not working for specific bundle identifier iOS
I'm integrating AdMob rewarded interstitial ads into my live iOS app using CocoaPods and package dependency management. The ads are working fine when I use the bundle identifier com.CreativeCub.ProgrammingHu, but when I use the correct identifier com.CreativeCub.ProgrammingHub, the ads stop working.
Here’s what I’ve tried:

Verified that the bundle identifier matches across Xcode and AdMob.
Double-checked the App ID and Ad Unit ID in the AdMob dashboard for com.CreativeCub.ProgrammingHub.
Reinstalled the AdMob SDK using CocoaPods.
Attempted to integrate AdMob using Swift Package Manager.
Created a test project to rule out potential issues with my existing project.
Despite these steps, ads only work when I use the shortened bundle identifier (com.CreativeCub.ProgrammingHu), which is not the correct one.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or know why AdMob might be rejecting the full bundle identifier?
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  TestAdmob
//
//  Created by Akshay on 05/10/24.
//

import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds
import AppTrackingTransparency
import AdSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADFullScreenContentDelegate {

    private var rewardedInterstitialAd: GADRewardedInterstitialAd?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     
      loadRewardedInterstitialAd()
  }
    func loadRewardedInterstitialAd() {
            let adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6978759866"  // Replace with your actual Ad Unit ID
            GADRewardedInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID: adUnitID, request: GADRequest()) { [self] ad, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Failed to load rewarded interstitial ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                rewardedInterstitialAd = ad
                rewardedInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
                print("Rewarded interstitial ad is ready.")
            }
        }
    
    
   
    
    @IBAction func showAction(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if let ad = rewardedInterstitialAd {
               ad.present(fromRootViewController: self) {
                   let reward = ad.adReward
                   print("User earned reward: \(reward.amount) \(reward.type)")
                   // Reward the user here (e.g., give in-app currency or extra lives)
               }
           } else {
               print("Ad wasn't ready")
           }
    }
    
    
    

}

extension ViewController {
    func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("Ad was dismissed.")
        // Load a new ad
        loadRewardedInterstitialAd()
    }

    func ad(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error) {
        print("Ad failed to present full screen content with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func adDidPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("Ad did present full screen content.")
    }
}


Please capture logs when it fails and update them in your question

Did you checked your id inside Google.plist?
